# Libraries to help implement a CLI in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, grammar, command-line-interface

I'm trying to implement a CLI type application in Ruby.

The CLI should accept commands using a grammar that I wish to define. I've found some leads on how to implement and parse a  grammar (RParsec) but I don't see how I can hook that up to some code to acutally execute the command.

Commands would be something like (very rough idea, I have experience with grammars beyond a languages course in University):

" create 50 widgets with property foo equals 'abc' "
" update all widgets where property foo equals 'abc' so property baz is 'xyz' "

I'd appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are libraries to help you build a CLI app, but not really to parse a grammar:

[Commander](http://visionmedia.github.com/commander)

[Canine](http://gist.github.com/211445)

I believe Ragel plays nice with Ruby.  Check out a beginner article [here](http://www.devchix.com/2007/12/13/a-hello-world-for-ruby-on-ragel/)

Comment: Treetop is a great parser for Ruby, btw